# Run Python virtualenv through Matlab

Tags: python, matlab, opencv, virtualenv

I am trying to run a python code through matlab using system commands on a mac. I need to run the python code on a virtualenv to use opencv but I keep getting erors when I use "workon cv" and "mkvirtualenv cv" even though it works fine on the terminal.

```
status1 = system('workon cv')
status2 = system(char(cmm))
```

**output**:

/bin/bash: workon: command not found

status1 =

127

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test", line 5, in 
    import cv2
ImportError: No module named cv2

Comment: cmm is just the python run command.

Comment: Just call the `python` binary in the `bin` folder of your venv with full path. No need to active it.